# Mapping into a tree of nested sequences

Tags: tree, mapping, common-lisp, sequences

I've coded a function that aims to map into an arbitrary tree of nested proper lists, somewhat analogous to the common lisp function `map-into`:

```
(defun map-into-tree (fn tree)
  "Destructive mapping into a proper tree."
  (cond ((null tree) nil)
        ((atom (car tree)) 
         (setf (car tree) (funcall fn (car tree))) 
         (map-into-tree fn (cdr tree)))
        (t (map-into-tree fn (car tree)) 
           (map-into-tree fn (cdr tree)))))

(defparameter *tree* '(1 (2) ((3)) (4 5) (6 ((7)))))
*TREE*

(map-into-tree #'1+ *tree*)
NIL

*tree*
(2 (3) ((4)) (5 6) (7 ((8))))
```

However, I'm not sure how to go about generalizing it for arbitrary nested sequences (like `map-into` for sequences). Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call `map-into` ;-)

```
(defun map-into-tree (function tree)
  (labels
      ((recurse (tree)
         (typecase tree
           (sequence (map-into tree #'recurse tree))
           (t (funcall function tree)))))
    (recurse tree)))
```

... or equivalently:

```
(defun map-into-tree (function tree)
  (typecase tree
    (sequence (map-into tree (lambda (u) (map-into-tree function u)) tree))
    (t (funcall function tree))))
```

Test:

```
(map-into-tree #'1+ (copy-tree '((9 10) (8 9 10 11 (12 13) () (11) () 13))))
=> ((10 11) (9 10 11 12 (13 14) NIL (12) NIL 14))
```

I am not sure what should happen with a tree which contains strings: do we really want to iterate over each character? As a matter of fact, this is what is done here above.

> I also notice that map-into works with sequences containing cons cells, but the corresponding map-into-tree does not, even though it uses map-into.

`(1 (2 . 3))` is a proper list with two elements, namely `1` and `(2 . 3)`. Since `map-into` does not recurse into elements, all it does is calling the function on both those elements. In your comment, this was `print`, which can print improper lists without problems.

The second element is a sequence: when you call `map-into-tree`, the function recursively calls `map-into` with this sequence, which happens to be an improper list. [`map-into`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_map_in.htm) expects a *proper sequence* and thus fails with improper lists.

Please note that in your question, you said:

> a function that aims to map into an arbitrary tree of nested proper lists

A tree with improper lists is not a valid input.

Finally, I notice you call destructive functions on literal data, like so:

```
(map-into #'print '(1 2))
```

The quoted list is a constant, modifying it at runtime is undefined behavior. That's why I first used `copy-tree` in my example.

> So would this work to handle all special cases [...]

Since there is already a typecase in place, it is sufficient to handle the special case of the `cons`; that works regardless of the type of value held in the `cdr` slot:

```
(defun map-into-tree (function tree)
  (labels
      ((walk (tree)
         (typecase tree
           (cons
            (prog1 tree
              (setf (car tree) (walk (car tree)))
              (setf (cdr tree) (walk (cdr tree)))))
           (sequence (map-into tree #'walk tree))
           (t (funcall function tree)))))
    (walk tree)))
```

Comment: Cool--the force is with you. I also notice that map-into works with sequences containing cons cells, but the corresponding map-into-tree does not, even though it uses map-into. For example: (setq x '(1 (2 . 3))); (map-into x #'print x) -> 1, (2 . 3); but (map-into-tree #'print x) -> error. Can you briefly explain why the error for dotted lists?

Comment: @davypough I edited the answer because it didn't fit in a comment.

Comment: So would this work to handle all special cases:

`(defun dotted-listp (item)
  (and (consp item) (cdr (last item))))

(defun map-into-tree (function tree)
  (typecase tree
    ((or string (satisfies dotted-listp)) (funcall function tree))
    (sequence (map-into tree (lambda (u) (map-into-tree function u)) tree))
    (t (funcall function tree))))`

Comment: @davypough Unfortunately for you, `last` doesn't work with improper lists either. With a correct `dotted-listp`, I'd still hesitate to use it to test the whole list before deciding what action to do with it. But if this is the semantics you want to implement, you don't have much choice. Here above, I added a variant in which improper lists are handled like proper lists, i.e. as sequences.

Comment: Exquisite, except for (map-into-tree #'1+ (list 1 2 3)) -> (1 2 3)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

```
(defun map-into-nested-list (fn nested-list)
  "Destructive mapping into a nested-list."
  (cond ((null nested-list) nil)
        ((atom (car nested-list)) 
         (when (car nested-list) (setf (car nested-list) (funcall fn (car nested-list))))
         (map-into-nested-list fn (cdr nested-list)))
        ((atom (cdr nested-list)) 
         (when (cdr nested-list) (setf (cdr nested-list) (funcall fn (cdr nested-list))))
         (map-into-nested-list fn (car nested-list)))
        (t (map-into-nested-list fn (car nested-list)) 
           (map-into-nested-list fn (cdr nested-list)))))

(defvar *a* (copy-tree '((9 10) (8 9 10 11 (12 13) () (11) () 13))))
;; => *A*
(map-into-nested-list #'1+ *a*)
;; => NIL
*a*
;; => ((10 11) (9 10 11 12 (13 14) NIL (12) NIL 14))
```

The function is similar to `map-into-tree`: the main differences are that there is a new, symmetric, branch in the conditional for the case in which the `cdr` is an atom, and the test for the “atomic” cases to apply the function `fn` only if the atoms are different from `NIL`.